# authentication for unique pdf file download for logged in user in website

Tags: php, authentication, pdf

There are different user for my website, and for each user there are separate PDF files, I want to give users privilege to download their files(but should not see the files of others users). Now I have created a login and I have the user-id in SESSION (I am using PHP for backend). So what is the secure way of accomplishing this task? Also how should I manage many of these PDFs on my server? (currently I have kept all the PDFs in one folder, but this seems insecure and I think these can easily be extracted by the un-authenticated user)

Answer (score 2):

At a high level:

1. Store your PDFs outside of your webserver document root. Make them completely inaccessible to direct browser access.
2. Write a PHP script to handle download requests. This PHP page can check the session user ID to ensure the user is requesting a file that they are allowed to access.
3. Use `header()` calls and `readfile()` to then send the appropriate PDF file to the user.

Feel free to come back and post a question when you've researched and worked on this, and have a specific question with code.